# I can´t get acces to public functions in a polymorphic list

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following class in Unity3D:

```
public abstract class Property{
    public abstract bool equals (int value);
}
```

And another one who inherits from it:

```
public class A : Property{
    int currentValue;

    // Constructor
    public A(int newValue){
        currentValue = newValue;
    }

    // Getter
    public int getCurrentValue(){
        return currentValue;
    }

    public override bool equals (int value){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

There is another class B that is equal to A.

And in the main function I have:

```
    List<Property> list = new List<Property> ();
    list .Add (new A (0));
    list .Add (new B (2));
    Debug.Log (list [0]); // Prints "A" -> It´s OK
    Debug.Log (list [1]); // Prints "B" -> It´s OK
```

But I want to print the current value of the object A, and I don´t understand why if I do `Debug.Log(list[0].getCurrentValue())`, I can´t access that function! But it´s public! What is going wrong?

Comment: because your list contains `Property` types, and `Property` only has one method on it - `equals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list contains elements of type `Property`:

```
List<Property>
```

Which has only one method:

```
public abstract class Property{
    public abstract bool equals (int value);
}
```

While any given implementation of `Property` *might* have other methods, it just as easily *might not*.  The compiler can't guarantee it.

If the method needs to be on all `Property` objects, add it to the `Property` class:

```
public abstract class Property{
    public abstract bool equals (int value);
    public abstract int getCurrentValue();
}
```

And override it in the derived classes:

```
public override int getCurrentValue(){
    return currentValue;
}
```

Then you can call `getCurrentValue()` on any element in your list.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that as I added a `new A(0)` to the list, I´d have acces to the mehod.

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` is a generic list of `Property` instances. So the compiler only knows that the elements of `list` (in this case `A` and `B`) are of type `Property`.

Since the abstract `Property` class does not have a method called

```
getCurrentValue()
```

the compiler shows the error that you see. It simply doesn't know that the element is actually of type `A` and that it therefore has that method.

If both `A` and `B` have the `getCurrentValue` method (and only if every subclass of `Property` should have it), you should add it to the `Property` class as well:

```
public abstract class Property{
    public abstract bool equals (int value);
    public abstract int getCurrentValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the object to it's type:

```
Debug.Log((list[0] as A).getCurrentValue());
```

or perhaps more clearly:

```
A a = (A)list[0];
Debug.Log(a.getCurrentValue());
```

Comment: You forgot the cast in your second example `A a = (A)list[0];`